# multipleDefine: Dojo AMD loader clashing with VideoJS library

Tags: javascript, dojo, video.js, loader, amd

I would like to upgrade to the latest https://videojs.com version, but it now uses an AMD loader, and this leads to trouble using Dojo at the same time.  How can I use both libraries simultaneously, or is it impossible currently?

Simply including both dojo.js and video.js and invoking require() myself leads to a crash:

```js
require(['dojo/parser'], function (parser) {
  console.log('hi');
  parser.parse();
})
```

```html
<script src="//vjs.zencdn.net/5.4.6/video.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.12.3/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<div>Watch the console for multipleDefine errors.</div>
```

For some reason the stack overflow Snippet does not produce this error.. but the same code in a CodePen does, in both Chromium and Firefox for me:  https://codepen.io/neekfenwick/pen/xpQrbG?editors=1010

Or the equivalent standalone test file (used in my screenshots later):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <script src="../lib/dojo-premierrange/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
    <script src="//vjs.zencdn.net/5.4.6/video.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        require(['dojo/parser'], function (parser) {
            parser.parse();
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

The error message that is logged:

```
Error: multipleDefine
    at c (VM289 dojo.js:9)
    at Na (VM289 dojo.js:30)
    at VM289 dojo.js:31
    at d (VM289 dojo.js:8)
    at ab (VM289 dojo.js:31)
    at r (VM289 dojo.js:28)
    at HTMLScriptElement.<anonymous> (VM289 dojo.js:33)
```

What seems to be the trouble is that video.js has a series of sniffs in which it attempts to detect a pre-existing AMD loader, which succeeds to find the Dojo one, but then it calls define with an empty array:

```
function(f) {
    if (typeof exports === "object" && typeof module !== "undefined") {
        module.exports = f()
    } else if (typeof define === "function" && define.amd) {
        define([], f)
    } else {
        var g;
        if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
            g = window
        } else if (typeof global !== "undefined") {
            g = global
        } else if (typeof self !== "undefined") {
            g = self
        } else {
            g = this
        }
        g.videojs = f()
    }
}
```

That 5th line, `define([], f)`, seems to be the problem.  This ends up with the situation in dojo's loader that defQ has an empty element, so that this code:

```
        runDefQ = function(referenceModule, mids){
            // defQ is an array of [id, dependencies, factory]
            // mids (if any) is a vector of mids given by a combo service
            var definedModules = [],
                module, args;
            while(defQ.length){
                args = defQ.shift();
                mids && (args[0]= mids.shift());
                // explicit define indicates possible multiple modules in a single file; delay injecting dependencies until defQ fully
                // processed since modules earlier in the queue depend on already-arrived modules that are later in the queue
                // TODO: what if no args[0] and no referenceModule
                module = (args[0] && getModule(args[0])) || referenceModule;
                definedModules.push([module, args[1], args[2]]);
            }
            consumePendingCacheInsert(referenceModule);
            forEach(definedModules, function(args){
                injectDependencies(defineModule.apply(null, args));
            });
        };
```

This ends up with `args[0]` being null, which results in the `module =` line assigning referenceModule, in my case `dojo/parser` .. but `dojo/parser` has already been loaded, and so `multipleDefine` is logged.

[image]

I don't know if the comment `explicit define indicates...` may be a clue, but I do think the test of `args[0]` failing and it falling back on `referenceModule` is causing the problem.  Very soon after this, `multipleDefine` is logged, and inspecting the details of the state when it is thrown shows `dojo/parser`.

[image]

Comment: Interestingly on codepen you first load dojo then videojs and this leads to problem as you described (first `Error: multipleDefine` followed by `Uncaught TypeError: parser.parse is not a function`). If you change order so videojs first and dojo second, codepen prints me `hi` message as expected.  Probably your codepen example is not enough to reproduce issue... or right order of JS imports solves it?

Comment: Thank you @andy.  That does indeed seem to fix it.. how annoying :) I will test this on the production codebase later, in the middle of some big jobs today that this can wait on.  If this pans out, I'll get back and you can write this up as an Answer I can Accept.  It would be nice to know how to use the includes in the original order I used, but your suggestion does seem to fix the problem as stated.

Comment: Hi @Neek, I just served another pair of eyes and asked question for you to resolve. If it works, I am glad to help. AMD loaders collisions is one of tough problems in fact, especially if different loaders try to be too smart or they have different origins.

Comment: Hi @Neek, any results from your tests?